# php retrieve random row from mysql only once

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, random

I'm trying do display random question for a quiz but I don't want repeat the same question in the quiz.

What I'm currently trying: function in my model to get a random question

```
public function getRandom()
{
$idarray = $this->session->userdata('list');
//get a random question
$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$row = $query->row();

//make sure same question is not displayed twice ?
while(in_array($row->id, $idarray))
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM questions_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $row = $query->row();
}

$idarray[] = $row->id;
$this->session->set_userdata('list',$idarray);




//get answers for that question and shuffle them
$query2 = $this->db->get_where('answers_table', array('qid' => $row->id));
$answers = $query2->result();
$shuff = (array)$answers;
shuffle($shuff);

return array('question' => $row, 'answers' => $shuff);
```

}

In my controller I have a function that is called when the quiz starts

```
$idarray = array();
$this->session_set_userdata('list',$idarray);
```

But when i try to run the quiz it doesn't respond.

Tried this:

public function getRandom($ids)
   {
    //ids is a session array passed in from the controller

```
$random = rand(0, count($ids) -1);
echo count($ids);

unset($ids[$random]);
array_values($ids);
$this->session->set_userdata('idlist',$ids);
echo $random;
```

}

Problem is sometimes the array doesn't decrease and same question is displayed i.e first count is 4 then 3 then 2 then 2 instead of 1.

Comment: How many questions do you have in the database? I wonder could you grab a list of all question Id's from the table and store them in an array. Generate the first random question $id = rand(0, count($questionIds)); Then using value, grab the question from the database and remove the item from the array. That way you're left with an array that contains the Id's of only the questions that are left.

Comment: A quiz is gonna have arround 25 questions probably.

Comment: In that case doing what I mentioned will probably work and require less queries on your database.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (untested);

```
function selectAQuestionId($ids) {
    $id = rand(0, count($ids));

    // Now we need to remove the question id from the ids array
    unset($ids[$id]);

    // And re-index the array, you need to do this
    array_values($ids);

    // Store the questionId and remaining question Ids, in an array to return
    $response['questionId'] = $id;
    $response['ids'] = $ids;

    // Return the question and remaining ids
    return $response;
}

// Grab a list of question id's from your database
// i.e. "SELECT id FROM questions"
$questionIds = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

// Grab a random question id and store the remaining questions ids
$response = selectAQuestionId(ids);

$questionId = $response['questionId'];
$ids = $response['ids']; // Ids now only contains the remaining question ids

// Use the $questionId, go get your question from the database
```

Next time you want to get another question, simple passed the returned ids array over to the selectAQuestionId function again.

Comment: I tried something similar with session array but sometimes the array size isn't decreased

Comment: It should decrease providing you reset the array index after you've performed the unset()